# Using redux as a client side caching, but is there a scenario where too much caching backfires on performance?

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux

I love how redux can be used for caching some data such that it does not need to be fetched again from the backend. But as I was doing it, I was wondering whether if there are any cons of doing it?

Theoretically in an app where every changes depend on the current user making changes, one could cache all data in redux so it's only fetched once in that session? Is there any major cons of this?

Comment: What happens if the user is using two tabs/windows? The changes from one will not be reflected in the other if you never fetch the data again. Depending on how your app is setup this might still make sense and be a non-issue, but if you are swapping between multiple views where affordance would make users think that data that is being shown on each view change is up to date then you might have an issue. Maybe something like SWR or Tanstack query would suit your needs better, they both support caching data and showing this data on subsequent requests while revalidating with the server.

Comment: @JacobSmit - Ah that's true. Thanks for the reference to the resources, will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

> I love how redux can be used for caching some data such that it does not need to be fetched again from the backend.

As long as your source of truth is the backend, you still need to send changes to it, if you're adding new data or modifying existing data. And you better do that right away, otherwise other uses of the backend won't see these changes.

> one could cache all data in redux so it's only fetched once in that session?

Not fetching the data again for a long time (or at all) has the disadvantage that it might become outdated, someone somewhere else might have written to the backend, and you can't see their changes.

You probably want to look into https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview - it advertises itself as a...

> powerful data fetching and caching tool. It is designed to simplify common cases for loading data in a web application, eliminating the need to hand-write data fetching & caching logic yourself.

There is a general approach that makes SPAs feel very responsive and fast via caching, which is to load any cached data from the redux store when looking at a record and fetching an up-to-date version of the record at the same time. If the record hasn't changed in the backend, it looks to the user as if it was loaded immediately. I believe that RTK Query employes this logic (never used it myself).

Comment: that's true but I was speaking in the scenario where no other user can make changes that are relevant to another user. So, it would not cause data being obsolete because some other user updated else where.

But as the other person mentioned, it can still go into a case where the user has multiple tabs open and one of the tabs has outdated data. 

Yeah RTK query seems promising, will take a look. Thanks!